# Compositor Backdrop disappeared

Tags: compositing-nodes

I have a little, though important issue with the Compositor. I had a Backdrop and everything worked well until I wanted to check what the Viewer Border checkbox does (red in the image). I clicked, the backdrop disappeared and I can't get it back in any way (unchecking the checkbox won't help). I also checked that it is file dependent, in a new file everything is ok. What to do?

[image: Compositor – Viewer Border checkbox]

Comment: sometimes it helps to ctrl-shift-click on the node again where you want your viewer node (auto-)connected.

Comment: yes, this I tried, but it still won't show up

Comment: hm, no idea then. i tried to recreate it by using that viewer border checkbox, but the backdrop still worked. if it's only your file, as you say, maybe transfer all the content into a fresh one?

Comment: Does it show nothing also if you connect other nodes to the viewer output? I see lots of nodes working with alpha and your render layer doesn't have a preview image. Are you sure that there is something to backdrop?

Comment: try ctrl + alt + b and fit operator.

Comment: @Carlo: I double checked connecting the Viewer to other nodes, and you were right, my mistake, it is due to the lack of preview in the RenderLayers node. Somehow there is nothing to backdrop. Ahhh! Got it. I had to turn off the sequencer in Post processing, and there is a RenderLayers preview again. It renders again! Woof, problem solved! :-)

Comment: Good! Consider to make a proper answer with what you discovered and mark it as accepted. Here in the comment is quite hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so this is the solution. I had to switch off Sequencer in the Post Processing tab. I had added an image-sequence to the sequencer at some point, which made the Sequencer rendering take over over normal 3D scene rendering. That is why the RenderLayers' node preview disappeared and consequently the backdrop, as there was nothing to display (from the last node in the hierarchy, I checked other nodes and they did display bits and pieces as should be). I somehow connected this behaviour with the Viewer Border checkbox which I checked and I got confused, but it seems it had nothing to do with it. Now that I have the RenderLayers preview and the backdrop back again, I can't replicate the behaviour of Viewer Borders affecting my backdrop.